# HOW to Put a text from a captcha image in a Textfiled In WATIR/FIREWATIR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, watir

I am using Watir and i have to put the value in a textfield from a captcha(image generated are different each time). So what should i do in this

Comment: Please explain why you'd want to do this

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says for [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA):

> A CAPTCHA ( /ˈkæptʃə/) is a type of challenge-response test used in
>   computing as an attempt to ensure that the response is generated by a
>   person

So, the purpose of CAPTCHA is to prevent automation.

If you are the part of the team that is developing the application (and not just trying to automate random web site), ask a developer what is the easiest way to automate that page. There are several solutions, from removing CAPTCHA in testing environment, to providing CAPTCHA value somewhere at the page (also only in testing environment)...